# Ansible provisioning without internet access

Tags: ansible, rhel, ansible-role

I know that you can setup proxy in Ansible to provision behind corporate network:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

like this:

```
environment:
    http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

Unfortunately in my case there is no access to internet from the server at all. Downloading roles locally and putting them under /roles folder seems solve the role issue, but roles still download packages from the internet when using:

```
package:
   name: package-name
   state: present
```

I guess there is no way to make dry/pre run so Ansible downloads all the packages, then push that into repo and run Ansible provision using locally downloaded packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Ansible, as all Ansible is doing is running the relevant package management system on the target host (i.e. yum, dnf or apt or whatever). So it is a question of what solution the specific package management tool provides, for this case.

There are a variety of solutions and for example in the Centos/RHEL world you can:

- [Create a basic mirror](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016)
- [Install a complete enterprise management system](https://spacewalkproject.github.io/)

There is another class of tool generally called an artefact repository. These started out life as tools to store binaries built from code, but have added a bunch of features to act as a proxy and cache packages from a wide variety of sources (OS Packages, PIP, NodeJS, Docker, etc). Two examples that have limited free offerings:

- [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype)
- [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/)

They of course still need to collect those packages from a source, so at some point those are going to have to be downloaded to placed within these systems.

Comment: thanks clockworknet, you are right, that it is probably more related to the package management tools

Answer (score 1):

Like clockworknet pointed out this is more related to the RHEL package handling. Setting up local mirror somewhere inside the closed network can provide a solution in this situation. More info on "How to create a local mirror of the latest update for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, 6, 7 without using Satellite server?": https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- Install Sonatype Nexus 3
- create one or more yum proxy repositories
  https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/yum-repositories
- use Ansible to add these proxies via yum_repository
  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html

  ````
       yum_repository:
         name: proxy-repo
         description: internal proxy repo
         baseurl: https://your-nexus.server/url-to-repo```
  ````

note: did that for APT and works fine, would expect the same for yum